# Google Translate API conversion

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, google-api, google-translation-api

Would anyone be able to help me with my translator using the google translate API? It comes up with an error on the very last line 
`System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from type 'TranslationResult' to type 'String' is not valid.'`
This is the code here

```
    Private Sub TranslateText(InputText)
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "C:\Users\student\Desktop\sunlit-runway-279702-175183ddeace.json")
        Dim Client = TranslationClient.Create()
        Dim InText = InputText.text
        Dim response = Client.TranslateText(InText, LanguageCodes.Japanese, LanguageCodes.English)
        Output.Text(response.TranslatedText)
    End Sub
```

When I use a message box it works however I want it to be displayed in a textbox

Comment: seems your are missing to typecast..typecast object to text as text accept string object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text is a property of textbox, not a function. To set the text of a textbox it's like this:

```
myTextBox.Text = "Hello word"
```

Not like this

```
myTextbox.Text("Hello world")
```

This is different to mesagebox.show which IS a function and DOES take a string parameter

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello World")
```

So, to set the textbox text to the translated result:

```
myTextbox.Text =  response.TranslatedText 'translated text is a string, like "Hello World"
```

---

Really I think your code should look like:

```
Private Function TranslateJapanese(inputText as string) as string
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "C:\Users\student\Desktop\sunlit-runway-279702-175183ddeace.json")
    Dim Client = TranslationClient.Create()
    Dim response = Client.TranslateText(inputText, LanguageCodes.Japanese, LanguageCodes.English)
    Return response.TranslatedText
End Sub
```

And be used like:

```
englishTextbox.Text = TranslateJapanese(japaneseTextbox.Text)
```